# Sum with multiple filters excel with or-operator?

Tags: excel, filter, sum, or-operator

Hi I would like to be able to sum in an excel using multiple filters and connecting them also be "OR". 
Let's say I have this List:

[image: See image]

to sum all the prices that belong to category "a" I used the following formula.

> {=SUM((KAT_1="a")*(PREIS))}

For all prices that belong to "open" likewise

> {=SUM((KAT_2="open")*(PREIS))}

If I want to sum only those prices that belong to "a" **and** "open" I used

> {=SUM((KAT_1="a")*(KAT_2="open") *(PREIS))}

Now my problem. If I want to sum everything that belongs to "a" **or** "open" 
I could try

> {=SUM(((KAT_1="a")+(KAT_2="open"))*(PREIS))}

But then it says 47. Which double counts those that are both "open" and "a".

How can I prevent this from happening?

One solution would be:

> {=SUM((((KAT_1="a")+(KAT_2="open"))-((KAT_1="a")*(KAT_2="open")))*(PREIS))}

But isn't there an easier way? 
Especially if you had a more complex list this ends up being very complicated.

Hope you understand my question!

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered SUMIFS()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the OR case you can:

```
{=SUM(IF(((KAT_1="a")+(KAT_2="open")>0),PREIS,""))}
```

(Replace + with * for the AND case, then you can have an elegant parallel construction)

Comment: Thank you very much. This perfectly helps!